# why not show any collection created in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I don't know what happen when I create a new collection in mongodb, for exampe, I have this code

I have this data in mongodb

```
> use mongo
switched to db mongo
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55431e3bdb99b7996f752f8f"), "name" : "David" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55431e42db99b7996f752f90"), "name" : "Juan" }
>
```

This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

//Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mongo", function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to mongodb");
});

//Model
mongoose.model('users', {name: String});

//Router
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
        res.send(users);
    });
});

//Server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server running");
});
```

this is the result in browser

[{"_id":"55431e3bdb99b7996f752f8f","name":"David"},{"_id":"55431e42db99b7996f752f90","name":"Juan"}]

So far so good.

when I create a new collection in the same database named "test" or other name, I can do find mongodb

```
> use mongo
switched to db mongo
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55501179b5ae498fb42a19e3"), "name" : "Iron" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5550238d82553eae20688f6c"), "name" : "Batman" }
>
```

my app.js modified with the new collection

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

//Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mongo", function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to mongodb");
});

//Model
mongoose.model('test', {name: String});

//Router
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    mongoose.model('test').find(function(err, test){
        res.send(test);
    });
});

//Server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server running");
});
```

this is the result in browser

[]

that's my problem, why my result in browser is empty.... please help me, I don't know what happen if my db.test.find() has data, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will pluralize the collection name, unless you give it a specific name to use. So, under the covers it's actually trying to use `tests` as the collection name. Add the name as the third parameter of the `model` declaration.

```
mongoose.model('test', {name: String}, 'test');
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, you solved my problem.

Comment: In this same example I have a new problem, why can't access a specific data from "model test", example, when send the data to view "mongoose.model('test').find(function(err, test){res.send(test)});" and on the view "jade", I put the var "test.name" it show me "undefined", I don't know why?? but if I put only var "test" this show me all data, what is my problem?? thank you.